# MongoDB Storage Engine on a collection level

Tags: mongodb

On MongoDB, Is it possible to change the database engine on a collection level? just like MYSQL does for  InnoDB and MyISAM.

Please let me know.

Thanks,

K

Comment: What storage engine? When does a storage engine work on a collection level in any db?

Comment: I believe storage engine is the software used to manage (delete, insert, update) data.

Comment: Manage in what way? can you explain fully what you mean? It sounds like you mean the lock and isolation levels of the databases software but I am unsure

Comment: INNODB and MyISAM are a bit misleading actually because the "storage engine" also contains the lock and everything else, MongoDB has only one storage engine, its own C++ programming and its lock only works on database level

Comment: what about GridFS? is it a different storage engine? can a collection be move there?

Comment: Gridfs is merely a driver implemented standard for storing files, it uses all the same storage internals as MongoDBs normal ops

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like you're trying to avoid answering the M102 exam final yourself :-(

Comment: This is question from M102 exam

Comment: Why are there so many UPs for the answer from @FGM? Because a lot of people are looking for the answer of M102 final exam lol.

Comment: For the record, I had this question today in the course of my actual job. Sometimes questions are on exams for a reason.

It is a pity that Mongo doesn't offer an "on disk, slow reads, fast-ish writes" storage option that isn't memory mapped for archival data.

Answer (score 4):

> **Note:** This answer applies to MongoDB 2.x. Since version 3.0 the situation has changed.

My answer is no.

The default memory-mapped storage engine is as far as I know the only MongoDB supported storage engine. When you start mongod there are no config options related to the storage engine. Such options at collection level, are even harder to imagine also would not be practical at all.

If you're interested in changing the engine behind MongoDB take a look at TokuMX for MongoDB http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokumx-for-mongodb/ or Spire for Mongo http://drawntoscale.com/announcing-spire-for-mongo/.

Comment: Regrettable, Spire appears no more to exist. From the Drawn to scale site: "Sadly, Drawn to Scale is no longer in operation.".

Comment: This answer is outdated. Since MongoDB 3.0 storage engines are pluggable and an alternative storage engine WiredTiger is available out-of-the-box.

Comment: The answer is outdated, as MongoDB 3.0 supports an additional engine (WiredTiger) but the response is always no. The engine can be defined only at the mongod level, and not at the collection (or database) level.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change the storage engine on collection level. MongoDB 3.0 provides the syntax `db.createCollection(...{storageEngine:...}...)` but it is only used to pass arguments to the new wiredTiger storage Engine already in use for the database. You cannot change storage engine for a created database. See [db.createCollection()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection).

Answer (score -1):

This will be possible in MongoDB 2.8: http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals

Comment: Not at the collection level (which is the asked question).

Answer (score -1):

Since MongoDB 3.0, different storage engines are supported on a collection level. MongoDB ships with two storage engines, the MMAPv1 storage engine which is basically the old one and the new engine WiredTiger.

The default storage engine can be set when starting `mongo` with the parameter `--storageEngine <engineName>` or with the config key [`storage.engine`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.engine)

But when you want to create a collection which uses a different storage engine, you can chosen it explicitly when creating a collection with the `db.createCollection` method:

```
db.createCollection(
   "<collectionName>",
   { storageEngine: { <engineName>: { <engineOptions> } } }
)
```

Comment: As noted in another comment this syntax is only for changing the storage engine options, not the storage engine to use for a collection